# How can I remove the word 'features' from the url?

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, url

In joomla, when choosing my one menu, it displays:

http://localhost/site/index.php/en/features/prices

But in all other menus it displays like:

http://localhost/site/index.php/en/about-us

I want to remove the word "features" from the url. 
How can I do it? Why does it display the url like that?

By the way, prices menu is a child menu of external url menu. 
Like this: Company--->Prices

Comment: Have a look at Menu Aliases ;)

Answer (score 1):

Joomla router creates folders from menu and content organization to reach the target component and element.

You can modify the Urls re-organizing your menus. For instance, creating a top-level menu item to an internal category.

Comment: While this answer is correct, you may want to modify it to say that Joomla treats content organization as Virtual folders with content in those virtual folders. Joomla does not actually create a true folder in the root of the site for content. Just a thought, your answer however is correct.

Comment: let me check it

Comment: Not solved yet this problem